# Run github julia code using jupyter notebook

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook, julia

I want to run this [github](https://github.com/gideonsimpson/JuBasicMD). The specific example I want to run is `muller_rwm1.jl`. I got up to a part of their code where it says
`push!(LOAD_PATH,"../src/")  using JuBasicMD include("potentials.jl")`
but I get an error that

> ArgumentError: Package JuBasicMD not found in current path:
>
> - Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("JuBasicMD")` to install the JuBasicMD package.

I am fairly new with all of this and just wanted to find a way to run this code page.

Comment: That project is not configured as a standard Julia Package, so it mess up with adding directories to the path. I opened an issue in their issue tracker asking them to format their project as a "standard" package. When they will do it you should then be able to use that code by just typing `] add JuBasicMD`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the developer on this package.  I believe i have set things up so that it will have basic package functionality (though I have not yet added it to the registry).  You can now do:

```
pkg> add https://github.com/gideonsimpson/JuBasicMD
```

and then you can use it as a standard package.  I have not yet updated the example codes, but you should be able to just comment out the `LOAD_PATH` commands, and they will work, though you'll still need to have that `potentials.jl` in the same folder.

I appreciate any/all feedback on this package.

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum, I finally sat down and registered this package, now named `BasicMD`, so you should be able to add it as a standard package in a few days, after the registries update.